# How open is SO for the possibility of monetary bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Many times someone have non-trivial questions that he can not solve by himself. An SO user will usually come to the site looking for answers from experts. If the question is simple for some expert, often he will end up with a satisfactory answer. But some times the question is not trivial and **would require too much effort from any candidate volunteer answerer**. This often ends up with the question never being answered, even after placing a bounty. Something that could improve this, I see, is **monetary bounties**. The idea I have is:

1. Someone places a monetary bounty on the question.
2. That question is promoted.
3. Once answered, the bounty is split equally based on the number of votes a certain answer received.

The third point is essential part, as it would prevent the scenario where a user places a bounty, waits for good answers and then just gives the money to himself in another account. As votes are community driven, the voting system itself would ensure the money is fairly split between those who worked on the matter.

Given that system would benefit both parties - questioners with complicate questions who are willing to give money for answers, and experts who are willing to accept a compensation to put some effort in an answer - I believe this could be a healthy, constructive addition to the site.

Furthermore, given the recent ascending of internet-based crypto-currencies such as Bitcoin, Litecoin and Dogecoin, we now have many excellent choices of currencies that are remarkably easy to integrate with the system in an automated, safe way.

What are your opinion on the subject?

Comment: Not all that much: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57850/pay-money-to-so-for-quick-support http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102817/add-bounty-similar-way-can-we-not-have-add-money

Comment: I see you guys don't like it. Still, I would love to see your arguments and reasonings, so, please, if possible, when downvoting, don't forget making a post!

Comment: @Viclib I think if you are proposing a change, the burden is at least as much on you to reason why it should be done.

Comment: @Viclib You were given links to several duplicate questions with lots and lots of reasons.  If you're interested, read them.

Comment: I like my Reputation more than money. I dont care if i lost 1$ but one Reputation.. OMG.

Comment: @Viclib If you have money to spend, there are already plenty of websites out there with capable coders you can hire to solve your problem. That is not a gap SO needs to fill.

Comment: I fancy the idea of tipping cryptocurrencies.

Comment: @Bart, I see, that is a shame, I am definitely not comfortable with most of those sites. The way SO works in general, from the tagging system, to the vote, comments and answers system is much more elegant, in my opinion. I wasn't ever able to get satisfactory answers from those sites and I have an overall feeling that most of them are filled with scams. I do think that something like a Bitcoin bounty would fit really well with SO's voting system, as that would pretty much ensure good answers and no scams. But I understand and respect if the community doesn't agree with me on this one! (:

Comment: @Servy, you do not understand, I was asking for links of questions with 500 bounties which were flooded with bad answers and flame wars. I read the provided links and that argument isn't even mentioned in any of those.

Comment: @Viclib I'm not sure what argument you're referring to.  No arguments were brought up under the comment thread here before I posted my previous comment.

Comment: @Sevy woops! Nevermind, I just confused comment threads. My request for arguments and reasonings were made simultaneously to Bart's post, but it appeared after, so I didn't notice you were refering that. I thought you were talking about my reply to Martijn Pieters's comment on the answer below. My bad.

Comment: You are requesting that we change intrinsic motivation for extrinsic motivation. Studies have shown that doing so leads to worse results, not better ones.

Comment: That is a good argument, but why wouldn't you link those studies?

Comment: Bitcoin's legal status is very difficult and people can get into trouble for that. unless the legal status is OK in most of the world, I don't think it's a good idea. Btw. what about tracking/anonymity ? these transactions can identify the average Joe pretty well via transaction in blockchain.

Comment: @Derfder http://bitlegal.net/ 9 countries where bitcoin is illegal or in contention. Most of the world is permissive or indifferent at this point. 

That said, this isn't a good idea as it doesn't really add anything, but it risks corrupting the community. I'd be okay with a tip bot in chat, but paying for answers seems like a dark road to go down.

Comment: The premise that the votes are community driven would be broken as soon as there would be money in play.

Answer (score 43):

To quote [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25621/140890) (community manager):

> If I know the answer but am not willing to put the time in to answer
>   your question for free... then I'm probably not gonna do it for $20
>   either.
>
> But someone will.
>
> Guaranteed, someone, somewhere has time to burn and needs cash. No
>   guarantee they know the answer, mind you... but they'll take a guess
>   at it. And since they really need that $20, they'll likely hang around
>   and down-vote any other answers, while picking fights with anyone who
>   criticizes theirs. Just look at the little fights people get into over
>   rep *now*, and spice it up with some desperation...
>
> So if you just want answers, and lots of 'em, but don't really care if
>   they actually answer the question... And if you *love* flame wars...
>   Then yes, this is a great idea.
>
> If you like anything about the way the site works now, then it's a
>   terrible idea.

So, no, this is a **terrible idea**.

Comment: Those are valid concerns, but yet, that is just speculation. He has no evidence any of that will happen and, in my opinion, the vote and moderation systems, plus the overall civilised, respectful attitude of SE communities, are more than enough to secure those from happening.

Comment: Have you **seen** the quality of some of the answers on 500 point bounty questions? Introduce money into the process and it'll only get worse. This is **not** mere speculation.

Comment: The few I've seen, bad answers are just straight downvoted by the community, so wouldn't get any money anyway. Could you link me some examples?

Comment: What about tipping?

Comment: Tipping sounds like a great idea, but wouldn't solve my particular problem (I have difficult questions and can't manage to get an answer).

Comment: @QF_Developer That is already entirely possible. Several users have links to Amazon wish lists or such things in their profiles. And that is no issue.

Comment: @QF_Developer: That already is available; individual users make their wishes known in their profiles. But that's entirely different from *offering money up-front*.

Comment: @Viclib: so, you are fine with flooding the site with terrible answers; but you won't get more *quality* answers just because you offer money.

Comment: @QF_Developer: If you want to offer money up-front, I am available for hire as well.

Comment: @Viclib: also, [Google Answers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Answers). They offered money for answers, they didn't last long.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but between those terrible answers someone might spend some time to actually solve the problem and give a quality answer. That person will obviously get upvoted, as usual, and get the money - not those who spam. That alone will be a motivation not to spam a thread, in the first place. I just think the problem you are proposing here is exactly what the site has already solved with the voting system.

Comment: @Viclib: the fallacy is the assumption that someone with the answer will not give it unless money is offered.

Comment: Someone without the answer but enough background to find it with some effort might only do it for a monetary compensation.

Comment: @Viclib: then post your question on something like [Uclue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uclue) where you can offer a bounty now, and see how that goes. I *personally* think this is a terrible idea, and will fight tooth and nail to keep it out of Stack Overflow.

Comment: As a counterexample to your argument, I often ask Three.js questions. There aren't so many people using Three.js and even less with enough knowledge about its source. Most of my questions often would need someone with that knowledge to look through the source and perform some tests before finding the answer. I have bounty questions on Three.js that are never answered due to this, but I managed to find and pay someone with the necessary knowledge to do it.

Comment: @Viclib: Sure, and he spent the time because you *hired* him. Up-front. Signed a contract probably. That's a very different setup from a bounty for the highest-voted answer on an anonymous website.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what is your real concern? How this could be destructive to you, personally? I'm asking this so I can address your concerns in an upcoming concrete proposal.

Comment: @Viclib: it changes the nature of the site entirely; from recognizing and trusting experts based on their shared knowledge to a money-fueled economy.

Comment: Not only does it change the nature of the site, the nature of participation, but it adds complexity to the codebase, adding money to the mix will only cause issues with people being dissatisfied on both sides, would make the quality of posts drop (extrinsic/intrinsic motivation at work). And more.

Comment: [Youtube: Joel Spolsky, on monetary bounties](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ&t=20m10s): "Karma [i.e., reputation] is based on the philosophy that you can't just pay people to answer questions."

Comment: This is wild, bizarre, speculation.

Comment: @JoeBlow You've got me curious. What part is speculation?

Comment: I meant the stated philosophy, is speculation.

Comment: Lets compare it to online games. In the F2P model, you can spend money on the game if you want to gain benefits. Games are fun, but often have flaws which make people annoyed. If you spent no money on the game, you'll either ignore the flaws or quit. Things are different when people spent money on the game. When money is involved people get crazy. When they are dissatisfied with something they not just let others know, they rage. On the other hand where some money can be made all kinds of scum will try to exploit it. With money involved any reputation drama will look like like child's play.