# Has there been any discussion for allowing urgent bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I use Stack Exchange fairly frequently. Unfortunately for me, when I am forced to turn to Stack Exchange for asking my own questions, it's because I've failed at figuring it out on my own and am in need of assistance. Even more unfortunate is that this is often walls I've run into at work, and am pressed for time on figuring it out.

I realize that the point of SE/SO isn't to be a safety net for this kind of thing - but let's face it, for some of us, some of the times, it is.

Has there been any consideration for the option of allowing a type of *speciality* bounties prior to the 48 hour window? When working on a hobby at home, 48 hours isn't that bad. When faced with deadlines, 48 hours can seem like a lifetime. For those of us working on a team with limited resources, SE/SO is our best bet at finding a prompt answer.

Comment: Consider that within 48 hours, you can do quite a lot to help yourself get an answer, even without a bounty. Improving the question, adding details, trying things and documenting what you tried and what didn't work... and of course respond to comments and requests for clarification.

Comment: Morally: I don't think it's fair to ask volunteers to answer faster.

Comment: Then there's always the question of what happens if someone starts using this for "PLZ HELP MY HOMEWORK IS DUE SOON" questions.

Comment: Since you asked, yes, this has been proposed many times before, and rejected each time.

Comment: @DennisMeng, thankfully most of those users don't have enough rep to give out bounties, but I agree with your point.

Comment: @gunr2171 The generalization of the point though; that people ask low quality close worthy questions and would bounty them to both prevent closure and attract answers, would become a significant problem, even if it's less of the "do my homework for me" variety.

Comment: Hmm, I see there are lots of points to consider with this. On the morality of it, I don't understand how that's a concern.. I mean, the whole bounty system is about rewarding volunteers to prioritize my post over someone else's. What's the difference between that and asking them to prioritize an urgent request over a non-urgent one, if it rewards more rep?

Comment: @Servy - very good point; I never even considered that.

Comment: @MrDuk: we have never done *URGENT*. If your task is that urgent, you can hire a consultant instead. My CodeMentor.io and Airpair.com rates are very reasonable!

Comment: This would likely get abused by people who's task aren't urgent, eventually resulting in all bounties being *"URGENT"*. Could combat that with a higher barrier of entry i guess. make it cost double the points, but i don't really see how that would help you get an answer faster just because the bounty is ending sooner.

Comment: See some discussion on MSE's [Why can't I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat): "*If you're allowed to offer it right away, then it has the potential to create an economy where people only focus on questions with bounties.*" The fear here seems to be that the value of imaginary Internet points would skyrocket (if they can get you an answer ***right. now.***) and would become a *necessary* component to attracting answers.

Comment: @DennisMeng - Right now, they just use moderator flags for those. I'm starting to use "urgent" as a keyword filter every day to see what flags I can decline immediately.

Comment: @BradLarson So, you mean; you have an *urgent* need to dismiss those flags quickly?

Answer (score 19):

You should not really be asking on Stack Overflow if your question is *that* urgent.

Stack Overflow is **wrong place to ask** if you have an urgent problem. While you might get an answer quickly there is no guarantee of this. It's not set up to get quick answers on complex problems, the only reason you get a quick answer on a simple question is because there's always *someone* browsing the site who knows the answer. The system isn't going to be changed to cater for this situation.

If your deadline is that close or the problem is critical to the project and you hit a brick wall with your problem, then you should be talking to your boss/client to explain the situation and agree a plan of action, not asking a rushed, possibly ill-thought out question on Stack Overflow.

This plan could be an extension to the project - by which time you might have an answer from Stack Overflow or have been able to start your bounty - or bringing in someone else to help etc.

Comment: The point wasn't that the question would be the make or break point for a deadline within that 48 hour window. It was that, even with a deadline 2 weeks away, a  48 hour delay on one element could cause an issue.

Comment: @MrDuk - The same argument applies.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it is basically saying "If you have this problem... well, you shouldn't have this problem". Sometimes things go wrong. Sometimes the problem is hard to fix the first time, but easy to fix the second time. In these cases early bounties would result in a good answer being posted 48hrs faster.

Comment: @sdgfsdh - what I'm saying is that Stack Overflow is **wrong place to ask** if you have an urgent problem. While you might get an answer quickly there is no guarantee of this. The system isn't going to be changed to cater for this situation either.

Comment: "It's not set up to get quick answers on complex problems" -- I would add to this something like, "It's not even set up to guarantee quick answers on simple problems." That would repel those trying to [justify urgency](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/839601) of zero effort questions like "oh my question seemed simple so I asked it hoping to get answer faster than by Google search"

Answer (score 9):

If you need urgent help, money can provide urgent help.

Comment: Just don't go [this route](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251576/how-open-is-so-for-the-possibility-of-monetary-bounties?rq=1)

Comment: What, you mean imaginary Internet points aren't like money to some people???